Why is the NTP time off relative to the NIST standard?
The NIST official U.S. time website shows the current UTC and also my device's time and calculates an offset, see attached screenshot:

To my surprise the time difference, which varies during the day, is often on the order of 1..2 seconds. I do understand that there could be all sorts of network delays but I still expected the NTP protocol to be more accurate than this.
As far as I can tell the difference is not due to NTP configuration errors because I have observed it on several machines:

On my mobile phone that uses my network carrier's time setup;
On my private laptop that connects to my own NTP server that syncs to several stratum-1 servers;
On a Mac desktop that gets its time from time.apple.com;
and also at work (I don't know how our IT dept set up their time servers though).

My question is whether this is "normal", or is there a way e.g. of connecting to particular NTP servers to achieve a higher system time accuracy, e.g. +/- 0.1s relative to NIST's UTC? Thank you.

I'd blame the latency to the website rather than your clocks. From the same machine, using two different browsers (one of which points at a VPN endpoint in Europe), I get a time difference difference :D Direct: +0.089 s ... VPN: +0.282 s  P.S.: You shouldn't be using Stratum-1 servers, they explicitly state that.


You should trust an NTP server much more than a clock on some website. Also, your NTP clients actively take the roundtrip time of your network connection into account. Does that website do that? Does it state any accuracy? So, forget that clock.
Yes, it's normal for device clocks to drift, and NTP clients to then slowly adjust them back to the correct time. 2s for a day might sound a bit much, but in any case, this is still more trustworthy than a clock on a website.

It's not that your NTP-synchronized computers are off the NIST standard (they are, but think of in "milliseconds"), that website as displayed in your browser is. NTP clients are the higher-accuracy tool to determine time than a browser receiving network packets!
If you care about the technicalities: all that this website shows is a one-time queried time, gotten via XML-HTTP request; this is the literal line of code:
xmlHttp.open("GET", "/zzz__longrandomstring.cgi?disablecache=" + d.getTime(), false);

and the comment above mentions "CGI". So we're talking about a 1990's/early 2000's webserver that just gets the time "right now at the time of asking", puts it in some high-latency HTTP data, sends it to your browser through a link of unknown and highly-variable network, uses that to calculate the offset once (from a single measurement) and displays it to you, updating the "UTC" time (not UTC at all) once a second (by measures of your local time keeping, not the actual UTC second) by adding 1 s to it.
This is literally a "how not to do time synchronization", in its purest form! This website is almost certainly from a time where "my PC time is gone, the CMOS battery ran out of juice" was a common thing to hear, and PC clocks were so bad, they drifted by minutes within weeks, and nobody had NTP clients.

Thank you for the very detailed explanations, +1. In the meantime I checked what the NIST website claims to be UTC against my "radio-controlled" wristwatch that I synced to the German DCF-77 sender and the two agreed, while the NTP time was 2 seconds behind. Maybe the difference is maybe not due to the NIST website's lack of modern Web technology or network latency.

it is. Again, an NTP client should be off at most by the jitter of your internet connection's latency (and it will be off much less on average), and that website is definitely off by the round-trip time + HTTP parsing overhead + Data handling in Javascript + DOM modification overhead. (notice: in the NTP case, it's the uncertainty in roundtrip that's the error, on the website it's the complete roundtrip) Assuming your 1s-accurate watch is more accurate than a properly synced NTP client: nope. DCF-77 has a good accuracy at its source, yes, but your watch still has 1s granularity.

So, maybe all your devices with NTP are systematically off- that would be very surprising, because NTP has actual correction mechanisms designed into so that something that is off (e.g. due to roundtrip delay) becomes corrected. Or, the single-ended website is off, which has no correction mechanism built in. It's a pretty clear-cut case to me :)

Yes, the watch has 1s granularity. However, if I hold the watch to my computer's display and compare it to the "NIST clock graphics" then I can see them "moving in sync", and I would be able to see a ~2s difference. Similarly, e.g. in the MacOS System Preferences I can display the computer's (NTP-based) time with 1s granularity and a ~2s difference to the watch, if there's one, would be clearly noticeable. Fun fact, this afternoon the NIST<->NTP difference disappeared on my work desktop -- maybe the network is less congested :-)

again, sorry for being a stickler to this, this is not a "NIST<->NTP" difference, this is a "unreliable website<->local NTP time" difference. That would indeed align well with your conjecture it might have to do with network load! NTP shows relatively little sensitivity to network load (both due to its small packet, ping-pong nature, and due to the aforementioned mechanism to simply cancel out the roundtrip delay in your network link), whereas HTTP requesting the time from a server is sensitive to that, especially in terms of connection establishment!

No, you are not a stickler :-) but a knowledgeable person who thinks in a precise manner. And what would timekeeping be without precise minds? I have learned a lot from your explanations and accepted your answer. Thanks again for your input.

@AndrásAszódi thank you for the kind words!
